# Need help identifying a mark on a tool

Tags: writing-identification

Apologies for cross posting from the woodworking stack exchange.

I ran across an auction of a set of Japanese chisels for woodworking. The only visible markings are stamped on the chisel itself, and I'm looking for any help identifying the kanji (assuming that's the proper term).

Here's a zoomed version of the faded markings with some sharpening:

[image]

I've sent a note to the auction house for more photos of the storage box or any other clarifying info, but I haven't heard back.

Thanks for taking a look!

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/140050/discussion-on-question-by-eyepulp-need-help-identifying-a-mark-on-a-tool).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The image is upside down.
The writing says "長弘" which is the tool's brand in Japan.

長 means "long", "always", "excel in", "leader" depending on the context.
弘 means "expansion", "enlarge", "liberal", "great"

I am not sure what is the true meaning, it depends on what the company wanted to convey here, but one could easily feels something big and prosperous from that.

[image]

Comment: Awesome -- thanks for the visualization -- you and @aguijonazo landed on the same characters. This traces to the Osahiro(Nagahiro) brand, more specifically a father/son blacksmith and likely the son who made this set.  He retired in his 90's and left quite a legacy with his tools.  Thanks helping with this!

Comment: @EyePulp in the visualization the 長 is not matching perfectly (it should be more tall) but you get the picture. I am on a quest to find out if this forum is welcoming new contributors or if I should give my free education time in another place. Cheers.